# how to write this loop For with an append of a function?

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, append

I am trying to make an append and it adds to "pr", the values of f(m), according to each m. The problem is that it returns "pr", having f only in m=1. How can I make it make me an append with each m of the for?
thanks!

```
def f(m = m):
    return 2*m**2+1

for m in range (1,10,1): 
    pr = []
    pr.append(f(m = m))

print(pr)
```

Comment: Remove both `= m`.

Comment: `pr = [f(m) for m in range(1, 10, 1)]`

Comment: What do you understand `pr = []` to do, and why do you probably not want that inside of your loop?

Comment: You are throwing away the result of the previous append on every iteration. `pr = []` goes *before* the loop, so that you are always appending to the same `list` object.

Comment: The first `=m` should be removed. The second one is harmless, though depends on you not changing the name of the parameter in the definition of `f`.

Comment: You should call your array out of the loop. Try like this :

    def f(m):
        return 2*m**2+1
    pr = []
    for m in range (10): 
        
        pr.append(f(m))
    
    print(pr)

Answer (score 1):

## `pr` initialization need to be outside the loop

```py
def f(m):  # =m removed as it's not a valid python syntax
    return 2 * m ** 2 + 1


pr = []
for m in range(1, 10, 1):
    pr.append(f(m=m))

print(pr)
```

If the `pr` variable is inside the loop, the list is reinitialized at each iteration of the loop, which leads to a list with only one element because only the last iteration is effective.